# emitter follower biased by input signal?

Tags: emitter-follower

[image]
For the standard emitter follower you typically need input coupling capacitors and a DC bias of roughly half the supply voltage however what if the input signal itself swings around half the supply voltage?

e.g if the previous stage to an emitter follower is a standard op amp non-inverting amp with a split supply (+12V,-12V) with the input referenced to centre point but the succeeding emitter follower is referenced to -12V (i.e +24V, 0V),
so The op amp output is referenced to ''+12v'' relative to the emitter follower?
Could this replace the input coupling cap and resistor biasing or would it not work?

Load would be a pair of headphones (50 to 300 ohm)

example of circuit is attached below

[image]

Differential emitter follower?
[image: differential emitter follower]

Inverting amp?

[image]

Comment: Draw the full idea of the circuit to stop ambiguity and sentences that make no sense.

Comment: I did.what sentences make no sense?

Comment: *but the preceding emitter follower* - what preceding emitter follower? Crop your diagram to fit the page to make it legible,

Comment: thanks for correction, it should be succeeding.
also fixed size of image... ms paint is not the best editing software

Comment: The board has a built-in schematic editor, which is better to use than paint for schematics.

Comment: fyi the first schematic was wrong and I just updated it.
sorry again for this trainwreck of a post, should have had my morning coffee first.

Comment: More ambiguity: *what if the input signal itself swings around half the supply voltage?* - do you mean a peak to peak swing of (+V minus -V)/2 or do you mean it is centred around the mid point of the two supply rails?

Comment: arounf the mid point of 2 supply rails

Comment: Should the load be connected to -12 V?  Could it be connected to ground? If so, there is no need of the capacitor... only disconnect R2 from the op-amp output and connect it to the transistor emitter.

Comment: @Circuitfantasis the EF cant drive negative current so I dont think connected output to ground would work.

Comment: EF = emitter follower? During the positive output voltage, the positive power supply +12 V  "pushes" positive current through the transistor into the load.  During the negative output voltage, the negative power supply -12 V "sucks" current  through the emitter resistor from the load. It would be useful to draw the current paths.

Comment: yep emitter follower. I am aiming for distortion  as good as the standard emitter follower above, is there any disadvantage with this compared to with single supply?

Comment: The emitter resistor should have quite lower resistance than your headphones; so better use a push-pull stage (add another but p-n-p transistor instead Re). The single supply will still need an artificial ground (middle point) for the op amp and coupling capacitors. In this case, there is no need to move R2 upper end (it is even better to stay where it is).

Comment: Thus finally you will invent all famous amplifying configurations:) Congratulations for the inventive passion! This is the so-called "bridge amplifier" where the load is driven from both sides in opposite directions (differentially).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has taken all the good information provided in answers and comments and moved them into their question. This then invalidates the answers and make those leaving answers look stupid. **DO NOT DO THIS**

Comment: What are you talking about? none of the answers are invalidated,  all that was added was 2 of my own alternative circuit examples as a reponse to comments, 1 of which was nothing to do with any of the info posted here.
 the only problem here is the site's bad system that wont let me add that circuit example in a comment  to not mess with the original question.

Comment: @andyaka Also I apologise as you had already given the answer to the intial question along with your alternative suggestion:
'Of course, if you really want the return current for your headphones to go via -12 volts (potentially noisier) then you will need an output capacitor.'

I should have marked this as the answer before following up with more questions, or perhaps start an entirely new thread for continuing the discussion?

Comment: @Jay I probably sounded harsh but, in the past, I've seen questions evolve faster than Darwin in a time machine and it really gets out of hand.  So I apologize if I sounded harsh. The simplest way is that you should avoid encompassing answers already given into your question without clear attribution because, anyone coming along in a month will think the answers are a bit lame (basically repeats of the question and they will attract down votes).

Comment: I understand, so would you recommend hosting the circuit images on external site to be able to link them in comments? Or starting a new question?
I personally dont like using external hosting sites as you will often see broken links from them on sites like this which ruins it for anyone finding it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Could this replace the input coupling cap and resistor biasing or
>   would it not work?*

A more convenient idea would be this: -

[image]

It's called a DC coupled amplifier and uses feedback directly from the emitter to set the gain at the output to be: -

$$1 + \dfrac{R2}{R1}$$

Of course, if you really want the return current for your headphones to go via -12 volts (potentially noisier) then you will need an output capacitor.

Comment: The issue is I cant really modify the op amp configuration as its part of the output buffer on a DAC PCB.

I was thinking there may be another option making use of the differential or ''balanced'' output  of this DAC.
A bridged amplifier that would recieve this differential signal from the DAC does not reference its output to ground, the headphone/speaker is basically 'floating' between the outputs of each half the bridged amp.
I added updated version of schematic to show what I mean.

Comment: This will not work because the NPN is in the loop and adds open loop gain making the circuit unstable.  The NPN will have to be a PNP in that case and resistors will have to be added/adjusted.

Comment: @le_top I don't think so - it's an emitter follower and has a voltage gain less than unity and is quite likely to have a frequency response many times greater than the op-amp hence, instability won't happen. If it were a MOSFET source follower, you'd have a more realistic argument.

Comment: Ok, my look at the circuit was a bit too fast. Sorry.

Comment: @Andyaka I added a version of your circuit to the OP that using inverting amp, do you see any issues with that?

Comment: An emitter follower operates in class-A and always draws a fairly high current even when there is no signal. Then it gets VERY hot.

Comment: @Jay you have taken every idea made in answers and comments and added them sequentially to your question. In my book this **takes the piss** out of anyone answering because your actions appear to move the goalposts each time an answer is made. This sort of thing has be done before and established members come down hard on perpetrators hard (YOU in this case). Do you see the problem? If you do this then you move the focal point from "the answer" (the free and good advice given to you for YOUR benefit) to your question. You should **roll-back ALL your amendments** and never, ever do this again.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5OcVA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then with suitable op-amp biassing so that its output swings somewhere between the rails, the emitter follower will 'follow' the output at about 0.7 V lower.

Comment: yes, thats it just if the op amp is configured as a non-inverting amp/buffer.
So the question is would referencing the op amp input  to ground take care of biasing?